# python dictionaries when keys are numbers

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary, numbers, key

I have a question about dictionary properties in python when the keys are number. 
in my case when I print a dictionary with number keys the result of print will be sorted by keys but in the other case (keys are string) dictionary is unordered. I want to know about this rule in dictionaries.

```
l = {"one" : "1", "two" : "2", "three" : "3"}

print(l)

l = {1: "one", 2: "two", 3: "three", 4: "four", 5: "five"}

print(l)

l = {2: "two", 3: "three", 4: "four", 1: "one", 5: "five"}

print(l)
```

result:

```
{'three': '3', 'two': '2', 'one': '1'}

{1: 'one', 2: 'two', 3: 'three', 4: 'four', 5: 'five'}

{1: 'one', 2: 'two', 3: 'three', 4: 'four', 5: 'five'}
```

Comment: Python dictionaries are intrinsically unsorted. You can't count on their order and it won't be preserved.

Comment: The reason your integer key dictionaries appear in the same order probably has to do with how Python caches small numbers. Print this dict `{500000: 'five', 400000: 'four', 30000: 'three', 200000000: 'two', 10: 'one'}` and you'll see the numerical order is no longer preserved.

Comment: thanks , i get my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python use [**hash table**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table) for storing the dictionaries so there is no ordered in dictionaries or other objects that use hash function.

But about the indices of items in a hash object, python calculate the indices based on following code [within `hashtable.c`](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/661cdbd617b8/Modules/hashtable.c#l317):

```
key_hash = ht->hash_func(key);
index = key_hash & (ht->num_buckets - 1);
```

So as the hash value of integers is the integer itself the index  is based on the number (`ht->num_buckets - 1` is a constant) so the index calculated by Bitwise-and between `(ht->num_buckets - 1)` and the number.

consider the following example with `set` that use hash-table :

```
>>> set([0,1919,2000,3,45,33,333,5])
set([0, 33, 3, 5, 45, 333, 2000, 1919])
```

For number `33` we have :

```
33 & (ht->num_buckets - 1) = 1
```

That actually it's :

```
'0b100001' & '0b111'= '0b1' # 1 the index of 33
```

*Note* in this case `(ht->num_buckets - 1)` is `8-1=7` or `0b111`.

And for `1919` :

```
'0b11101111111' & '0b111' = '0b111' # 7 the index of 1919
```

And for `333` :

```
'0b101001101' & '0b111' = '0b101' # 5 the index of 333
```

For more details about python hash function its good to read the following quotes from [python source code](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/661cdbd617b8/Objects/dictobject.c#l106) :

> Major subtleties ahead:  Most hash schemes depend on having a "good" hash
>   function, in the sense of simulating randomness.  Python doesn't:  its most
>   important hash functions (for strings and ints) are very regular in common
>   cases:
>
> ```
> >>> map(hash, (0, 1, 2, 3))
>   [0, 1, 2, 3]
> >>> map(hash, ("namea", "nameb", "namec", "named"))
>   [-1658398457, -1658398460, -1658398459, -1658398462]
> ```
>
> This isn't necessarily bad!  To the contrary, in a table of size 2**i, taking
>   the low-order i bits as the initial table index is extremely fast, and there
>   are no collisions at all for dicts indexed by a contiguous range of ints.
>   The same is approximately true when keys are "consecutive" strings.  So this
>   gives better-than-random behavior in common cases, and that's very desirable.
>
> OTOH, when collisions occur, the tendency to fill contiguous slices of the
>   hash table makes a good collision resolution strategy crucial.  Taking only
>   the last i bits of the hash code is also vulnerable:  for example, consider
>   the list `[i << 16 for i in range(20000)]` as a set of keys.  **Since ints are their own hash codes, and this fits in a dict of size 2**15, the last 15 bits of every hash code are all 0:  they *all* map to the same table index.**
>
> But catering to unusual cases should not slow the usual ones, so we just take
>   the last i bits anyway.  It's up to collision resolution to do the rest.  If
>   we *usually* find the key we're looking for on the first try (and, it turns
>   out, we usually do -- the table load factor is kept under 2/3, so the odds
>   are solidly in our favor), then it makes best sense to keep the initial index
>   computation dirt cheap.

Comment: tnx, your answer was perfect ;)

Comment: @FarazMolaee Welcome, I was looking for the source to add more explanation but it sounds very twisted!!!!

Comment: @FarazMolaee checkout the edit!